# How to set each and every row of a ListView to transparent in Android?

Tags: android, listview, background

I have a `ListView` in which the rows are generated using a `SimpleAdapter`. I have three `TextViews` and two `ImageViews` in it. I have set the background of the `ListView` as  `android:background="@drawable/backgnd"`.The TextView's background is set to the following `android:background="#20535252"`. I am getting a nice glass/transparent kind of background where the TextViews are placed, but I don't get a glass like background at the whole row of the ListView. Can anyone suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is fully depends on which color your choosing in your layouts and you can modify the color transparent by adjusting the the values like below

```
    android:background="#80xxxxxx"
    (or)
    bg.setColor(Color.argb(128, xxx, xxx, xxx));
    (or)
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Use this and in that xxxxx fields add your Back ground color it will give your Smooth like a glass color backgrounds... All the best...

This is the custom Adapter You just use this I have used some layouts in this Adapter you will just put your Custom layout in this adapter

```
   CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, mListItems);
   mPullRefreshListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And use this custom adapter in your  project

**And don't forgot i suggested above the color so use that color in you List item background it will**

**your desired background**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Sample> {

public ArrayList<Sample> mlist;
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Sample> mlist) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.mlist = mlist;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(Sample item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public Sample getItem(int position) {
    return mlist.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mlist.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  //replace here your layout 
    TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
    text1.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem1());
    text2.setText(mlist.get(position).getListitem2());
    text2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // you just put your Logic here And use this custom adapter to
            // load your Data By using this particular custom adapter to
            // your listview

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

 }
```

Comment: I am using a background image and not a color in the background of the Listview. So I want a glass like color on top of the background. Is it possibe?

Comment: ya it's definitely possible i will post the Custom adapter for your listview you will use this Definitely it will Help you